# SwiftUI ForEach nested in ScrollView breaks onPreferenceChange

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I am trying to get the current **scroll value** of a `ScrollView` to be used elsewhere in other views.

It appears the only way to do it is using `GeometryReader` and store its value in a `PreferenceKey` to be then read by `onPreferenceChange` so that we do not change the state of the view during rendering (which is forbidden).

Everything seems to work fine until I embed a ForEach in the scrollview instead of some static views. Then the `onPreferenceChange` stops receiving events.

Here is a **NON** working example:

```
struct ScrollViewPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {

            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear.preference(key: ScrollViewPreferenceKey.self,
                                       value: proxy.frame(in: .named("scrollview")).minY)
            }

            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(0..<27) { item in // this is causing the issue
                    Text("Item \(item)")
                }
            } //end vstack
        } //end scrollview
        .coordinateSpace(name: "scrollview")
        .onPreferenceChange(ScrollViewPreferenceKey.self, perform: { value in
            let _ = print(value)
        })

    }//endbody
} //endview
```

*As result nothing is printed*

Replacing the `ForEach { }` with hardcoded views works just fine:

```
                Group {
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                }
                Group {
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                }
                Group {
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                    Text("Item x")
                }
```

Results in printing the correct values

> 0.0
> -11.666666666666664
> -49.333333333333336
> -104.33333333333334
> -174.33333333333331
> -252.66666666666666
> -315.0
> ...

I figure there must be some issue with the scrollview and dynamic content but what and how to solve it?

The issue happens even if the ForEach is embedded several layers of View deep in the herarchy or in other files.

Is this just another SwiftUI bug or there is something i am not grasping (I am new to the framework)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {

            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear.preference(key: ScrollViewPreferenceKey.self,
                                       value: proxy.frame(in: .named("scrollview")).minY)
            }

            ForEach(0..<27, id: \.self) { item in // this is causing the issue
                Text("Item \(item)")
                    .padding()
            }
        } //end scrollview
        .coordinateSpace(name: "scrollview")
        .onPreferenceChange(ScrollViewPreferenceKey.self, perform: { value in
            let _ = print(value)
        })

    }//endbody
} //endview
```

worked. The VStack was causing the problem.

Comment: This is so weird, and sadly i need the VStavk, thisvis a simplified problem. :/ also do you know the reason? Thank you

Comment: You can also make it work by putting the GeometryReader below the VStack. Not sure if those are the numbers you're expecting tho. Not really sure why it doesn't work as you originally had it, sorry.

Comment: Yes! it works also putting the `onPreferenceChange` directly on the `GeometryReader`. One day we will know if a bug or a feature i guess. Thanks